# Return a list of column names as new column based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data for each customer and product looks like below :

```
Customer  P1   P2   P3   P4   P5   P6 
c1        10   2    43   21   11   4 
c2        1    3    32   1    6    3  
c3        20   4    20   72   78   80
c4        30   80   31   31   29   20
```

I want the output as follows :

```
Customer  P1   P2   P3   P4   P5   P6   Top_Products (based on scores)
c1        10   2    43   21   11   4    [P3,P4,P5]
c2        1    3    32   1    6    3    [P3,P5,P2]
c3        20   4    20   72   78   80   [P6,P5,P4]
c4        30   80   31   31   29   20   [P2,P3,P4]
```

Explanation of output : I am sorting the scores of products horizontally for each customer, and taking the column names of top 3 scores(descending order ) and putting in a list as a new column as "Top products" for each customer.

Eg. for 1st row, p3, p4 and p5 have highest scores(sorted in the best scores) and are put in another column as list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get all `P` columns with `iloc` and get positions of sorted values by  [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), use indexing and last convert values to lists:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]

df['Top_Products'] = df1.columns.values[np.argsort(df1.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, :3]].tolist()
print (df)
  Customer  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  Top_Products
0       c1  10   2  43  21  11   4  [P2, P6, P1]
1       c2   1   3  32   1   6   3  [P1, P4, P2]
2       c3  20   4  20  72  78  80  [P2, P1, P3]
3       c4  30  80  31  31  29  20  [P6, P5, P1]
```

If performance is not important or small number of rows use [`Series.nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) with convert index to lists:

```
df['Top_Products'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3).index.tolist(), axis=1)
print (df)
  Customer  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  Top_Products
0       c1  10   2  43  21  11   4  [P2, P6, P1]
1       c2   1   3  32   1   6   3  [P1, P4, P2]
2       c3  20   4  20  72  78  80  [P2, P1, P3]
3       c4  30  80  31  31  29  20  [P6, P5, P1]
```

EDIT: For top3 values by highest scores is answer very similar, only add `-` for `-df1.to_numpy()`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]

df['Top_Products'] = df1.columns.values[np.argsort(-df1.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, :3]].tolist()
print (df)
  Customer  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  Top_Products
0       c1  10   2  43  21  11   4  [P3, P4, P5]
1       c2   1   3  32   1   6   3  [P3, P5, P2]
2       c3  20   4  20  72  78  80  [P6, P5, P4]
3       c4  30  80  31  31  29  20  [P2, P3, P4]
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for your super answer. I have edited the question , now I want the list to be in order of highest scores

Comment: Thanks , its showing me error : "bad operand type for unary - :list"

Comment: @Mighty - How working `df1.columns.values[np.argsort(-df1.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, :3]]` ?

Comment: error is gone , but now its giving me Customer in that list too

Comment: @Mighty - do you use `df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]` for remove column `Customer` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
# filtering on product data
x = df.loc[:,'P1':]
# find arguments of lowest k values for each row
k = 3
top_k = x.values.argpartition(range(k))[:,:k]
# assign result as a new column
df.assign(Top_Products =[*np.asarray(x.columns)[top_k]])

  Customer  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  Top_Products
0       c1  10   2  43  21  11   4  [P2, P6, P1]
1       c2   1   3  32   1   6   3  [P1, P4, P2]
2       c3  20   4  20  72  78  80  [P2, P1, P3]
3       c4  30  80  31  31  29  20  [P6, P5, P1]
```