# Get the names of Top 'n' columns based on a threshold for values across a row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's say, that I have the following data:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
        Student_Name    Maths    Physics    Chemistry    Biology    English
0       John Doe        90       87         81           65         70
1       Jane Doe        82       84         75           73         77
2       Mary Lim        40       65         55           60         70
3       Lisa Ray        55       52         77           62         90
```

I want to add a column to this dataframe which tells me the students' top 'n' subjects that are above a threshold, where the subject names are available in the column names. Let's assume `n=3` and `threshold=80`.
The output would look like the following:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        Student_Name    Maths    Physics    Chemistry    Biology    English  Top_3_above_80
0       John Doe        90       87         81           65         70       Maths, Physics, Chemistry
1       Jane Doe        82       84         75           73         77       Physics, Maths
2       Mary Lim        40       65         55           60         70       nan
3       Lisa Ray        55       52         77           62         90       English
```

I tried to use the solution written by @jezrael for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137920/return-a-list-of-column-names-as-new-column-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas) question where they use [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get the positions of sorted values for the top 'n' columns, but I am unable to set a threshold value below which nothing should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first replace not matched values by missing values in [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), then applied solution with [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). Filter by number of `True`s of for count non missing values in [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace not matched values to empty strings.

Last are values joined in list comprehension and filtered out non matched rows for missing value(s):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]

m = df1 > 80
count = m.sum(axis=1)
arr = df1.columns.values[np.argsort(-df1.where(m), axis=1)]

m = np.arange(arr.shape[1]) < count[:, None]
a = np.where(m, arr, '')

L = [', '.join(x).strip(', ') for x in a]
df['Top_3_above_80'] = pd.Series(L, index=df.index)[count > 0]
print (df)
  Student_Name  Maths  Physics  Chemistry  Biology  English  \
0     John Doe     90       87         81       65       70   
1     Jane Doe     82       84         75       73       77   
2     Mary Lim     40       65         55       60       70   
3     Lisa Ray     55       52         77       62       90   

              Top_3_above_80  
0  Maths, Physics, Chemistry  
1             Physics, Maths  
2                        NaN  
3                    English
```

If performance is not important use [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) per rows, but it is really slow if large DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
m = df1 > 80
count = m.sum(axis=1)

df['Top_3_above_80'] = (df1.where(m)
                           .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.nlargest(3).index), axis=1)[count > 0])
print (df)
  Student_Name  Maths  Physics  Chemistry  Biology  English  \
0     John Doe     90       87         81       65       70   
1     Jane Doe     82       84         75       73       77   
2     Mary Lim     40       65         55       60       70   
3     Lisa Ray     55       52         77       62       90   

              Top_3_above_80  
0  Maths, Physics, Chemistry  
1             Physics, Maths  
2                        NaN  
3                    English
```

**Performance**:

```
#4k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
#print (df)

def f1(df):
    df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
    m = df1 > 80
    count = m.sum(axis=1)
    arr = df1.columns.values[np.argsort(-df1.where(m), axis=1)]

    m = np.arange(arr.shape[1]) < count[:, None]
    a = np.where(m, arr, '')

    L = [', '.join(x).strip(', ') for x in a]
    df['Top_3_above_80'] = pd.Series(L, index=df.index)[count > 0]
    return df

def f2(df):
    df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
    m = df1 > 80
    count = m.sum(axis=1)

    df['Top_3_above_80'] = (df1.where(m).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.nlargest(3).index), axis=1)[count > 0])
    return df

In [210]: %timeit (f1(df.copy()))
19.3 ms ± 272 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [211]: %timeit (f2(df.copy()))
2.43 s ± 61.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Your first suggestion fits my need.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
res = []
tmp = df.set_index('Student_Name').T
for col in list(tmp):
    res.append(tmp[col].nlargest(3)[tmp[col].nlargest(3) > 80].index.tolist())
res = [x if len(x) > 0 else np.NaN for x in res]
df['Top_3_above_80'] = res
```

Output:

```
    Student_Name    Maths   Physics     Chemistry   Biology     English     Top_3_above_80
0   JohnDoe     90  87  81  65  70  [Maths, Physics, Chemistry]
1   JaneDoe     82  84  75  73  77  [Physics, Maths]
2   MaryLim     40  65  55  60  70  NaN
3   LisaRay     55  52  77  62  90  [English]
```

Comment: You're welcome. As @jezrael pointed out, it will be slower with large dataframes